# Deadlock while using multiprocessing to speed up Pywikibot with Wikidata?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, wikidata, pywikibot

I’ve been having problems with speeding up Pywikibot. I’ve seen related questions here on StackOverflow, but they only partially apply to my problem:

- I set `throttle=False` wherever I could, but the bot is still very slow.
- I can’t use the `PreloadingPageGenerator` like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501483/how-to-speed-up-pywikibot) because I am not using the Bot to access Wikipedia but Wikidata. In my case, the requests look something like this

  ```
  from pywikibot.data import api

  request_parameters = {
       'action': 'wbsearchentities',
       'format': 'json',
       'language': language,
       'type': 'item',
       'search': name,
       'throttle': False
  }
  request = api.Request(site=self.wikidata_site, use_get=True, **request_parameters)
  response = request.submit()
  ```

I now tried to use `multiprocessing` so multiple requests can be sent to the API at once which removes the necessity to wait for the response before you can proceed with the next request, which looks like this

```
while not queue.empty():  # Queue holding data for requests
    job_data = [queue.get() for i in range(number_of_processes)]

    jobs = [
        multiprocessing.Process(
                target=search_for_entity,
                args=(name, language)
            )
        for name, language in job_data
    ]

    for job in jobs:
        job.start()

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
```

But the moment I run the program, it doesn’t even finish the first request because it gets stuck. I followed the bug to `pywikibot/data/api.py:1500 submit()`:

```
 rawdata = http.request(
                site=self.site, uri=uri, method='GET' if use_get else 'POST',
                body=body, headers=headers)
```

through `pywikibot/comms/http.py:361 fetch()`:

```
request = _enqueue(uri, method, body, headers, **kwargs)
request._join()
```

to `pywikibot/comms/threadedhttp.py:359 _join()`, where an acquired lock never seems to get released

```
def _join(self):
    """Block until response has arrived."""
    self.lock.acquire(True)
```

My question now it: Is this a bug of `pywikibot`? Have I applied `multiprocessing` to this problem in a wrong way? Are the any other solutions in my specific situation to speed up `pywikibot`?

Answer (score -2):

This code part is very outdated and threadedhttp module as you have shown is dropped years ago. I propose to update your Pywikibot.

Comment: This is not answer.

Comment: It is. You can't do any improvements like speeding up for an outdated framework.